# Android CursorLoader not working in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cursorloader

I have a FragmentActivity which implements the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks interface and I would like to change it to just a Fragment so that I can start it in the background of my splashscreen to grab information from my database.  However, when I change FragmentActivity to Fragment I get an error in onCreateLoader:

```
public class CursorLoaderTest extends Fragment implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

...
...

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1)
{
    // Grab URI corresponding with menuItem table
    Uri CONTENT_URI = TabletContentProvider.MENU_ITEM_CONTENT_URI;
    // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS 
    return new CursorLoader(this, CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
}
```

It wants me to change the CursorLoader object constructor to:

```
CursorLoader(Context);
```

And that obviously won't work.  I'm working on a project with a team and I'm in charge of the database operations so I'm not super familiar with Fragments / FragmentActivities because I'm not writing code for those parts of the application.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) has two constructors - the one you're using there, and one which takes simply a `Context` (which is what your IDE is suggesting as the correct constructor).

The one you're calling requires a `Context` as the first argument. When in an `Activity` you can pass `this`, as an `Activity` is a `Context`. A `Fragment` is not a `Context` though, so instead of passing `this`, you'd pass your containing activity:

```
return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```